# Updating only .svn folders

Tags: svn, version-control

I keep accidentally corrupting my .svn directories using sed (I forget to add the directory exclude), and this yields the happy svn error when I try to update or commit: `svn: Checksum mismatch for '.svn/text-base/foo.bar';`

(On a side note, I wish svn trusted the server enough to ignore the local text-base files if there is a mismatch instead of just dying)

My current solution is to checkout into a different directory, then delete every file except the .svn using:`sudo find . -type f -not -iwholename "*.svn*" -exec rm -r {} \;`  and then just cp recursively those files back into the original directory.

Is there anyway using svn to just gab the .svn files from the server and replace the current ones, or am  I stuck checking out, deleting, then pasting?

Comment: What about fixing your real problem? WHY do you keep corrupting your .svn directory with sed? Fix THAT problem, and you won't need to worry about it. You shouldn't be touching the contents of .svn at all, ever!

Comment: The reason isn't a coding issue (I know HOW to exclude the directory), it's just I keep forgetting to do it when I run sed. Notice I said `accidentally`.

Comment: What version of SVN are you using? I don't see a .svn/text-base in my working copies under SVN 1.8. I tried corrupting a few files in .svn/pristine instead, thinking maybe "svn cleanup" would fix things, but actually "svn update" worked without error in my case anyway (although neither update nor cleanup restore the "pristine" files to a correct state). For what it's worth, the files under .svn/pristine don't have file extensions matching the files in the working copy data which they correspond to.

Comment: Maybe create a sed alias that excludes the directory for you?

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to add the sed alias I guess. And I'm pretty sure my company is on like 1.4 or something old like that.

Comment: Update: when I tried updating to a specific revision after corrupting my .svn directory, I get: "Error: Checksum mismatch while updating {file path}:  
    expected:  f4223cf83f055b7d14980a93969dce76  
      actual:  5ce4e85ef0aa7345d829abec08780219  
Try a 'Cleanup'. If that doesn't work you need to do a fresh checkout."  

Cleanup doesn't fix anything as I mentioned; so I think your best bet is to avoid corrupting the .svn directory in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway using svn to just gab the .svn files from the server and replace the current ones

For the same WC it can be somehow tricky, but *I think* checkout empty new WC (with only `.svn` dir in it) will be acceptable solution.

I order to get such WC, you have to call checkout with `--depth 'empty'` parameter and copy resulting .svn into broken WC

Comment: This just sets the checkout depth to 0, so none of the children are  downloaded. I can probably use this to write a small script for this to work recursively, check this out http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html